# Concat integers as binary strings to bytea

Tags: postgresql

is it possible in PostgreSQL 8.4 to concat multiple integers (`int4`) values to a bytea value?

For example:

```
5::int4 || 1::int4
```

should result in a bytea value with `(0x05 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00)`, assuming a little endian machine.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `int4send` will convert an int4 to a bytea, but I suspect from the name it will always use network ordering.

that is:

```
steve@steve@[local] =# select int4send(3);
  int4send  
------------
 \x00000003
```

event on an amd64 machine.

Answer (score 1):

An indirect conversion can be made with `select byteain(bit_out(5::bit(32) || 1::bit(32)))` or `select int4send(5)||int4send(1)` which results in `0000000000000000000000000000010100000000000000000000000000000001`.

You could also use [binary string functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-binarystring.html) to convert to your desired encoding. See [Maarten Foqué's answer](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/integer-to-little-endian-conversion-td1928406.html) on the pgsql-general list for a solution to a similar problem. You should be able to simple concatenate the resulting `bytea` values from his function or a similar function (but mark it as stable instead of volatile).